# Python requests headers read

Tags: python-3.x, get, request

I made a python dirbuster but I can't prove how the page actually exists, I'm using status codes, still not working

```
import requests as req 
import sys,time,socket
#site = input(sys.qrgv[0])
site = 'https://www.example.com'
dosya = open('tr.txt','r')
dirb = dosya.readlines()
dosya.close()
for i in dirb:
    url = site+'/'+i
    print(url)
    time.sleep(0.8)
    istek = req.get(url)
    if istek.status_code == 200:
        print(f" [+] Found=> {url} ")
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can't prove the page exists